# PowerShell Script for Email Notification

Tags: powershell, email, smtp, smtpclient, filezilla

I am using a FileZilla Server as an FTP. I want to create a PowerShell script that will send an email as soon as a file is uploaded.

I have been using the knowledge in this article: https://richjenks.com/filezilla-email-notifications/

and below is the code of my fn.ps1 file

```
$EmailFrom = "SENDER_EMAIL"
$EmailTo = "RECIPIENT_EMAIL"
$Subject = "New File Uploaded to FileZilla"
$Body = "A new file has been uploaded to the FTP server on FileZilla"

$SMTPServer = "127.0.0.1"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 21)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("GMAIL_ADDRESS", "GMAIL_PASSWORD");

$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

The only problem is that no email is actually sent? I can see the PowerShell pop up briefly after a file is uploaded so it is being run upon file upload, however no email is actually sent anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am not entirely sure what is the relationship between "SENDER_EMAIL" and "GMAIL_ADDRESS", I found the above solution on another website and they are different, should these not be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you understand that the script actually has nothing to do with your FTP server. It is just a plain PowerShell script that sends a fixed email. So everything in the script is related to your SMTP mail server, not to your FTP server. So...

- What goes to [`SmtpClient` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.-ctor#system-net-mail-smtpclient-ctor(system-string-system-int32)) is the address of your SMTP mail server. You seem to be using an address of your FTP server.

  ```
  $SMTPServer = "127.0.0.1"
  $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 21)
  ```

  Check the example you have based this on. They use `smtp.gmail.com:587`.
- Similarly, what goes to `SmtpClient.Credentials` are credentials to your SMTP mail server. So some real values, not placeholders like these:

  ```
  $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object 
  System.Net.NetworkCredential("GMAIL_ADDRESS", "GMAIL_PASSWORD");
  ```

  For Gmail they would be your Gmail address and password.

Comment: Hey - This makes sense, Thank You. I have made the changes.

So the '$EmailFrom =' is not the same email that I will be putting in the 'SmtpClient.Credentials' ?

Comment: Typically they would be the same.

Comment: Great Thank You! All that was left to do was to allow less secure app access on the gmail account (created specifically only for this) and it works fine, accepting answer.